# Make a nested module be available globally in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to remove the nested path to import a module. Instead of importing like `import common.common1.bar` I want to be able to import like `import bar`

I have the following folder structure:

```
functions
|-- function_1
    |-- foo.py
common
|-- common_1
    |-- bar.py
```

What should I do in order to make the following import inside `foo.py`?

```
# foo.py
from bar import fun1
```

Comment: What about `from bar import *`? **(however, this is not recommended!)**

Comment: If you don't want to have ``bar.py`` as part of the ``common.common_1`` package, why is it placed in there to begin with?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'm building a aws lambda, but there's a resource called aws layer that makes a module globally available to all lambdas referencing it. In the development environment I want to simulate the same behaviour so I can perform some tests. The folder structure will be used later to make the CD/CI working properly.

Answer (score -1):

just copy the `bar.py` in to the function_1 directory or folder. and that should be it. then you can use `from bar import fun1`

Comment: I need to do it without copying

Answer (score -1):

Unless if you are using Python 3.3+ there is a need to define the full path? If it doesn't work, try creating an empty **init**.py in the common_1 directory

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).